# Tag merge / synonym request: [float] → [floating-point]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [float](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/float) (10 questions) into [floating-point](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) (32), and make them synonyms.

---

Preference for master tag is because it looks unambiguous and because Wikipedia article uses this term: [Floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully completed the merging of these two tags.